# Vue.js: How can I trigger one function with multiple events on the same element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue and I want to bind **multipe** events to a **single** function **in the same element**, something like the following (in plain JavaScript, feel free to run the code snippet):

```js
let mainElement = document.querySelector("h1");

// I made an 'events' array to loop
["click", "mouseenter", "And we can keep adding events..."]
.forEach( event => {
    mainElement.addEventListener(event, myFunction);
  }
);

function myFunction() {
  // DO SOMETHING, for example:
  mainElement.style.color = "red";
}

const resetButton = document
.querySelector("button")
.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mainElement.style.color = "black";
});
```

```html
<h1 style="color: black">This is the element we want to control</h1>

<button>Reset</button>
```

In Vue.js I can bind **ONE SINGLE EVENT** directly to an element like this:

```
<h1 @mouseenter="myFunction">This is the element we want to control</h1>
```

I want to know if there is a way to bind **MULTIPLE EVENTS** to a single function inside the same element, does anyone know if there is a syntax like this?

```
<h1 @[mouseenter,click,mouseleave...]="myFunction">This is the element we want to control</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if I am still correct.

```
<h1 v-on="handlers">This is the element we want to control</h1>

// ...

data() {
  const vm = this;

  return {
    handlers: {
      mousedown: vm.myFunction,
      touchstart: vm.myFunction
    }
  }
},

function myFunction() {
  // DO SOMETHING, for example:
  mainElement.style.color = "red";
}
```

haven't done vue in a long time, but if I am correct this still should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response!, By the way, can I ask what version of Vue does that syntax belong to? I'm learning the version 3 and so far, I haven't seen a "const vm = this" declaration, thanks!

Comment: I think I wrote this last time in vue2. Haven't used vue in a long time. And the "const vm = this" is just to make sure we still use the same this element. There are many opinions about writing it like that, because some will allow it and some say it is not best practice. Personally if it works it is all right ;)

Comment: It worked! I didn't need to declare the "const vm = this", just used "this" directly.

On the other hand, is there a way to use the "@" in this syntax? I tried to do it  like the following but it didn't work:

<h1 @"handlers">This is the element we want to control</h1>

Comment: Great! That is good to know for the future that "const vm = this" is not needed anymore. If i am correct then is the @ == v-on so v-on:click becomes @click. I don't know if it would work if you use @ instead of v-on (so you have @="handlers"). If that is not possible then I fear that I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I wrote it like that because of some problems with this, but it is some older code. Probably now would do more research if I could prevent it somehow in the situation I was in. But agree if not needed then don't do it.